# How to disable and/or change date range for Plot.ly GANTT date quick slectors?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

We are rendering a GANTT chart with Plot.ly (via Plotly.py). The GANTT has some buttons along the top to quick-toggle date ranges:

[image: Plot.ly GANTT quick date toggles]

How can we:

- disable the quick date toggles, and/or
- select specific date interval buttons to be more relevant to our data (such as 1d, 1w)?